# How to repeat given HEX string

Tags: bash, batch-file, hex, repeat

Suppose that I have a 7 byte file, named test.dat.
If I open test.dat with a HEX editor, the code will be

1F 2E 3D 4C 5B 6A 70

(The code has no significant meaning. Just for test!)

Now, what I want generate 7000000 byte file, it may be called milliontest.dat, by repeating this hex code 1000000 times. Batch, or bash is welcomed.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Using perl `perl  -e 'print "\x01\02"x10' > file.hex` change to match your milage

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to _convert_ the bytes in test.dat file to its Ascii code written in hex digits and insert a space between each one? This would produce _three output bytes_ per each input byte. However, from your description ("7 byte file 1000000 times = 7000000 byte file) it seems that you just want to copy the file 1000000 times: `(for /L %%i in (1,1,1000000) do type test.dat) > millionTest.dat`

Answer (score 5):

The **Easy-Way**

```
@echo off    
(
For /l %%n in (1,1,1000000) do copy milliontest.dat /B + test.dat /B milliontest.dat /B
) >nul 2>nul
```

The **Fast-Way**

This work very fast (0.2 seconds on my old machine) and it is pure dos batch solution.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

>test.dat set /p ".=1234567" <nul
copy test.dat /B tmp.dat >nul

set Times=1000000

(
 for /l %%n in (1,1,31) do (
    set /A "bit=Times %% 2, Times/=2"
    If !bit! equ 1 copy milliontest.dat /B + tmp.dat /B milliontest.dat /B
    if !Times! gtr 0 (
        copy tmp.dat /B + tmp.dat /B tot.dat /B 
        del tmp.dat
        ren tot.dat tmp.dat
    ) >nul 2>nul
 )
) > milliontest.dat

del tmp.dat

exit /b
```

As Aacini as noted, I explain this method. This method as how multiply the bytes of file test.dat for one million. This use the [Bynary Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Peasant_or_binary_multiplication).

> "In base 2, long multiplication reduces to a nearly trivial operation.
>   For each '1' bit in the multiplier, shift the multiplicand an
>   appropriate amount and then sum the shifted values. Depending on
>   computer processor architecture and choice of multiplier, it may be
>   faster to code this algorithm using hardware bit shifts and adds
>   rather than depend on multiplication instructions, when the multiplier
>   is fixed and the number of adds required is small."

**More simple way**

This way reduce the number of copy command. Every 10 copy reuse the result.
For achieve the result this use 6 cycles for one million as the number of zero is six.

```
copy test.dat /B tmp.dat >nul /B
copy tmp.dat /B milliontest.dat /B 

For /l %%d in (1,1,6) do (
  For /l %%n in (1,1,9) do copy milliontest.dat /B + tmp.dat /B milliontest.dat /B
  copy milliontest.dat /B tmp.dat /B
) >nul
```

For doubling file I have probed to use:

```
type tmp.dat>>tmp.dat
```

But an error occours, than I used COPY instead.

***EDIT:*** Substitute the TYPE command with COPY Always. The TYPE work on Text File.

Comment: This is a very nice solution.  It would be nicer if the input file, 'test.dat', was not changed.  It would also be good to have just one `copy`, instead of two, in the doubling step.

Comment: Hi pjh, I have edit the script for the first tip. I have difficult to use one copy only. What is the exact syntax?

Comment: I have substitute the second copy with a delete+rename. This is more fast.

Comment: Thank you, it's so fast. But it looks less intuitive. Guess there may be even faster and more intuitive method.

Comment: HI imida k, I have added the easy way. I have eliminating the TYPE use, because it work only on text file, On the fast way the speed change from 2 second to 0.2 second!

Comment: Adding a more intuitive and fast way than easy way

Comment: I think that the "more intuitive" method it is not... Yes, the "log10" of a number is its number of zeros, but this explanation immediately arise two questions: **1.** What happen if the number of times have _not_ just trailing zeros? Non-integer logarithm = the method don't work. **2.** Anyway, what happen if the first digit is not 1? An additional `for` would be required. None of these points are explained... @imidak: IMHO a small explanation of the binary system used in the fast method would be much clearer.

Comment: Hi Aacini, I have Revisionated: Added explain on Fast way. Changed Intuitive way in SIMPLE way. Removed LOG10 referement. Used in specific case of one million.

Comment: I like your mod, it is clearer/simpler this way (sorry, but I can't upvote more than one time :-). Did you saw my method [at DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6986&p=45491#p45491)?  It keep a redirected file open in order to grow it in same place, without re-copy the first part of the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "hex_string=1F 2E 3D 4C 5B 6A 70"

(for /l %%# in (1;1;1000000) do (
    (break|set /p=%hex_string% ) 
))>>hex_file
```

this will print the hex string into file 1000000 times.If you want to read a file as hex you can check [certutil](http://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html)

Comment: You are redirecting once per iteration, which slows it down. Put an extra set of parens around the entire FOR loop to speed it up significantly. But this still will be fairly slow.

Comment: Also, the hex string represents byte values, not a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

With Guxutils sed

`for /L %a in (1,1,999999) do @(sed.exe -ri "s/(.{7})(.*)/\1\2\1/" "test.dat")`

`sed.exe -ri "s/(.{7})(.*)/\1\2\1/" "test.dat"`
will get the first 7 HEX in test.dat, the rest HEX and add the first 7 HEX to the end.Then replace test.dat.

But this will re-write the test.dat to the disk 999999 times.

**Updated,**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "s_1="
for /L %%a in (1,1,100) do (set "s_1=!s_1!+")
for /L %%a in (1,1,3) do (
  "%sed_path%\sed" -ri "s/.*/%s_1:+=&%/" "test.dat"
)
exit /b
```

The Updated code can do the funtion quickly and only write to the disk 3 times.

Or
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

```
set "s_1="
for /L %%a in (1,1,1000) do (set "s_1=!s_1!+")
for /L %%a in (1,1,2) do (
  "%sed_path%\sed" -ri "s/.*/%s_1:+=&%/" "test.dat"
)
exit /b
```

This will write 2 times.

But according to the limitation of command length. It cannot run as

```
set "s_1="
for /L %%a in (1,1,1000000) do (set "s_1=!s_1!+")
"%sed_path%\sed" -ri "s/.*/%s_1:+=&%/" "test.dat"
exit /b
```

If "test.dat" have to keep,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "s_1="
for /L %%a in (1,1,1000) do (set "s_1=!s_1!+")
for /L %%a in (1,1,2) do (
  "%sed_path%\sed" -r "s/.*/%s_1:+=&%/" "test.dat"
)>>test2.dat
exit /b
```

Comment: Surely sed must have its own repeat mechanism requiring only a single sed instantiation, thus avoiding FOR /L. I'm pretty sure that strategy would be much faster.

Comment: `sed` can only operates once. [www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-7). I found a efficient way in `for` loop. Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A pure batch solution is likely to be fairly slow.

You could use my [JREPL.BAT regex text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) to achieve a simple and speedy solution. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged output.

```
jrepl ".*" "Array(1000000+1).join($0)" /m /j /f "test.dat" /o "millionTest.dat"
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried for this but the utility looks so helpful in many ways..!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear.  I think the stuff about HEX is irrelevant, and the requirement is to copy 'test.dat' into 'milliontest.dat' one million times.  A moderately efficient way to do that in Bash, with `cat` and `xargs` is:

```
for i in {1..1000000} ; do echo test.dat ; done | xargs cat >milliontest.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

This Bash code generalizes two of the solutions provided by Einstein1969:

```
readonly srcfile=test.dat
readonly multiplier=1000000
readonly destfile=milliontest.dat

readonly base=100

readonly tmp1=$(mktemp)
readonly tmp2=$(mktemp)

declare -i mult=multiplier
curr_src=$srcfile
curr_dest=$tmp1

# 'curr_src_list' is an array containing $base copies of the current source
# file path
declare -a curr_src_list="( {1..$base} )"
curr_src_list=( "${curr_src_list[@]/*/$curr_src}" )

# Initialize the (final) destination file
echo -n > "$destfile"

# Exit immediately if the multiplier is zero or the source file is empty
(( mult == 0 )) && exit 0
[[ -s $srcfile ]] || exit 0

declare -i rem scale
while (( mult > 0 )) ; do
    # Loop invariant: (final $destfile) == mult * $curr_src + $destfile

    rem=mult%base
    div=mult/base

    if (( rem != 0 )) ; then
        cat -- "${curr_src_list[@]:0:rem}" >> "$destfile"
        mult=mult-rem
    elif (( mult == base )) ; then
        cat -- "${curr_src_list[@]}" >> "$destfile"
        mult=0
    else
        # Determine number ($scale) by which to duplicate $curr_src and divide
        # $multiplier.
        if (( div < base )) ; then
            # Will finish on the next iteration.  Copy a smaller amount to
            # the temporary file now to minimize wasted copying.
            scale=div
            mult=base
        else
            scale=base
            mult=div
        fi

        cat -- "${curr_src_list[@]:0:scale}" > "$curr_dest"

        # Current destination becomes new current source
        curr_src=$curr_dest
        curr_src_list=( "${curr_src_list[@]/*/$curr_src}" )

        # Other temporary file becomes new current destination
        [[ $curr_dest == "$tmp1" ]] && curr_dest=$tmp2 || curr_dest=$tmp1
    fi
done

rm -f -- "$tmp1" "$tmp2"
```

Setting `base=2` gives "The Fast-Way".  Setting `base=10` gives the "More simple way".  Setting `base=100`, as in the code above, means that the required output is produced with just 3 `cat` operations.  It runs in around 3 hundredths of a second on an ancient Linux system.  With `multiplier` set to a billion (1000000000) it runs `cat` 5 times and completes in just over 11 seconds on a fairly modern Linux system.
The algorithm is basically the standard long multiplication algorithm.  The code could be a bit simpler, but at the cost of sometimes copying much more data to temporary files.  This code (with `base=100`) should do at most 1% of its copying to temporary files